# alternatives to the long definition outside template class

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a template class, and I wanted to define `operator=` outside the class:

```
template<uint32_t total_count, uint32_t init_count, uint32_t node_count>
class cls
{
    ...
    cls & operator= (cls && c);
    ...
};

template<uint32_t total_count, uint32_t init_count, uint32_t node_count>
cls<total_count, init_count, node_count> & 
cls<total_count, init_count, node_count>::operator= 
(cls<total_count, init_count, node_count> && c)
{
    ...
}
```

are there alternatives to the above definition except shortening template parameter names?

Comment: `cls<total_count, init_count, node_count> && c` can be simply `cls && c`

Comment: also, using a trailing return type: `auto ... -> cls&` (the "..." is not actual syntax here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of the definition does repeat the template parameters more often than necessary. The function's qualified name tells the compiler that the context is the `cls` class template with the specified template parameters. After that point, any occurrence of `cls` (without parameters) can be assumed to mean this context, similar to what you did within the template definition. So the explicit template parameters in the parameter list are not necessary; a simple `cls` there would be assumed to mean `cls<total_count, init_count, node_count>`.

A syntactic trick can similarly simplify the return type. The [trailing return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function), introduced in C++11, allows the declaration of the return type to occur after the function's name introduces the context. As with the parameter list, once you are in the correct context, the template parameters can be omitted.

```
template<uint32_t total_count, uint32_t init_count, uint32_t node_count>
auto cls<total_count, init_count, node_count>::operator= (cls && c) -> cls & 
{
    ...
}
```

*Community wiki because these simplifications were given in comments, by POW and parktomatomi.*